# QueryDSL Like operation on Number

Tags: java, querydsl

I have to search a number-field with wildcards. The corresponding JQPL query would be like this:

```
SELECT e From Entity e where e.personNumber LIKE :numberPattern
```

numberPattern is a String like this: "1??2" and e.personNumber is a Number on the Database (H2).

If i run this with JQPL it's no Problem at all but I can't put it into a queryDSL query.

when I try to

```
andBuilder.and(entity.personNumber.stringValue().like(numberPattern)
```

I get a

```
org.apache.openjpa.persistence.ArgumentException: "str (" bei Zeichen 7 gefunden, erwartet wurde jedoch ["(", "+", ...
```

If i try to do it like this:

```
Constant<String> constant = (Constant<String>) Expressions.constant(personNummer);
PredicateOperation predicateOperation = new PredicateOperation(Ops.LIKE, entity.personNumber, Expressions.constant(constant));
```

the result will be a

```
Data conversion error converting "1*"; SQL statement:
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1*"
```

So, is there a way to have a like operation on an number field with queryDSL?

Comment: For sure it must be 1??2 and not 1*

Comment: `Constant<String> constant = (Constant<String>) Expressions.constant(personNummer);
PredicateOperation predicateOperation = new PredicateOperation(Ops.LIKE, entity.personNumber, Expressions.constant(constant));`

Would have worked as well if would have put in % instead of * or _ instead of ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Did you try this

```
PredicateOperation predicateOperation = new PredicateOperation(Ops.LIKE,
  entity.personNumber, Expressions.constant("1%"));
```

I will see why the stringValue() expression doesn't work for OpenJPA.

Comment: With QueyDsl 4 it works directly with `entity.personNumber.like("%1")`