# QueryDsl with mongodb: Need help in String comparison with mapPath

Tags: java, mongodb, querydsl

I have a mongo query that is producing results as expected, here is my Query

```
db.getCollection('student').find({books: {$elemMatch: {"dynamicData.subject":/bbb/}}})
```

I have prepared a query using query dsl which is

```
orFn.accept(student.books.any().dynamicData.get(subject).eq(value))
```

Which is working fine for the exact match of value, I need the query to behave as sql like syntax to filter based on contains ignore case. Need help from some querydsl gurus

Comment: Solved the issue with help from [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400722/querydsl-like-operation-simplepath)

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution, [found it from here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32400722/querydsl-like-operation-simplepath)

```
Path<?> path = student.books.any().dynamicData.get(subject);
Expression<String> constant = Expressions.constant(value);
orFn.accept(Expressions.predicate(Ops.STRING_CONTAINS_IC, path, constant));
```